# Can one define a cross product for functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, cross-product

The dot product $c = \sum_i a_i b_i$ can be easily be generalized for continuous functions like
$$
c = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(x) b(x) d x
$$
But can one also generalize the cross product $c_{ij} = (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)$ to continuous functions in a similar way?

Comment: If using the analogy with vectors, then maybe such a "cross product function" $c(x)\not\equiv0$ should have the property $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}c(x)(a(x)-b(x))dx=0$$ since for vectors $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}=\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{c}=0$. If you could find such a $c(x)$ for given $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ then you are free to define it.

Answer (score 2):

let
$$c(x,y)=a(x)b(y)-a(y)b(x)$$